# Problemas al tratar de utilizar Project Loom/Virtual Threads con OPENJDK 19-loom JAVA

Tags: java, hilos, java-8, rendimiento, proceso

estoy tratando de probar el proyecto loom referente de los virtual threads en Java y estoy utilizando la versión del JDK 19-loom siguiente:

[image: Version de java de JDK que estoy utilizando]

```
package com;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

public class a {


    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception{
        Runnable printThread = () -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());

        ThreadFactory virtualThreadFactory = Thread.builder().virtual().factory();
        ThreadFactory kernelThreadFactory = Thread.builder().factory();

        Thread virtualThread = virtualThreadFactory.newThread(printThread);
        Thread kernelThread = kernelThreadFactory.newThread(printThread);

        virtualThread.start();
        kernelThread.start();

    }
}
```

Y tengo la configuracion siguiente de intelij:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero estoy teniendo el error siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y es que al parecer no se identifica el builder del thread

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber que mas necesito?

Comment: Tienes definir el "Project language level" en 19 o en "X - Experimental features".

Comment: intellij no me permite agregar X Exprimental feactures, pero utilice "javac --release 19 --enable-preview prueba.java"en el comand pront para ejcutar el metodo main de mi clase prueba y sigue sin reconocer el builder en thread Thread.builder.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes hacer es actualizar el IntelliJ para poder tener disponible el nivel de compilador "X - Experimental features" (yo estoy usando la versión 2021.3 y esta lo trae).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego debes actualizar tú código puesto que el método `Thread#builder()` ya no existe (por lo menos en la *build* 19-loom+2-58). En la API de esta versión indica que para crear *builders* tanto para *threads* virtuales como para los de plataforma debemos usar los métodos [Thread#ofVirtual()](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#ofVirtual()) y [Thread#ofPlatform()](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#ofPlatform()) respectivamente. Por lo que tú código debe quedar parecido a este:

```
ThreadFactory virtualThreadFactory = Thread.ofVirtual().factory();
ThreadFactory kernelThreadFactory = Thread.ofPlatform().factory();
```

**P.D.**: Lo parámetros por línea de comandos que le pases al compilador o al binario de java, como lo que indicas en tú comentario (`javac --release 19 --enable-preview prueba.java`), no tiene efecto en el IDE, por lo que aunque indiques el nivel del compilador de este modo no podrás autocompletar código desde el IDE de acuerdo a dicho nivel.